# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="cp850" standalone="no"?> become <?xml version="1.0" encoding="850" standalone="no"?> when using jdk1.8.0

Tags: java, xml, encoding, java-8, transformer-model

In jdk1.6.0, "cp850" can show in the xml declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="cp850" standalone="no"?>
```

however when i use jdk1.8.0, the encoding type become "850", without "cp"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="850" standalone="no"?>
```

How can I make the encoding become "cp850" when using jdk1.8.0?

I have tried to hardcode the xml declaration. Although the encoding become "cp850", it seems not is the right ways.

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");  
writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\""+encoding+"\" standalone=\"no\"?>");
```

I also compared two java version library and found that both of them have rt.jar. 
In Java SE 8, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html Cp850 have a new Alias or Aliases named "850" is this related?

Original Code

```
 String encoding = "cp850";
 transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encoding);
```

Thanks in advance, Neko